# CSS media queries not working properly (layout looks zoomed out on mobile phone)

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am using media queries for responsive layout  in my site.
Now I am trying on device with viewport width 320px.
Below is my CSS code for it:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */

#wrapper,#white-board,#content {
width:400px;
}
#slot {
width:370px;
}

#logo {
width:100px;
}
#top-bar-content,#nav-bar-tile,#card,#fourth-box,
#eighth-box-wrapper,#eighth-box,#ninth-box-wrapper,
#ninth-box,#seventh-box-wrapper,#seventh-box,#fifth-sixth,#sixth-box,#ad_long ,#sidebar {
display:none;
}

}
```

This is how it looks :

[image]

This is how it looks when I zoom In and this is what I exactly want the layout to be:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">` to the head

Comment: Yes it works now but I am now getting lots of space on the right for vertical scroll, why is this? My body content fits the screen perfectly ,still there is vertical scroll.

Comment: Would add a screen shot to see what's going on ?

Comment: I forgot to resize my footer so it was getting me some space for vertical scroll. Problem solved thanks a lot for your time, have a good time :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: If not working on mobile device or in chrome. Even you try this things for declare media css for support in all screen like mobile, ipad and desktop

@media screen and (max-width:1024px)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a viewport meta in your  :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```